# How do I create a Python Placeholder for Elements that are Empty parsed from an XML File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to start off by saying I am very new to Python, but I love the language.

Problem: 
I was provided a very large Juniper Configuration file in an XML format. I am using ElementTree library to parse through the file. The file has 5 main roots (parents) and several nested children. We are trying to append the text to several list from several element tags and display the data. I have verified the paths to each. I think the problem is some elements are empty, so when I display the data from each of the list, the corresponding data output does not match with what is within the XML document. Is there a way to tell ElementTree when parsing the document and appending the element to a list, if an element text is empty append "none" as a string?  An element placeholder so to speak. My hope is that when I display the data of several lists, it will match with what is within the XML document because the same number of elements were accounted for in the iteration for each list.

Thank you!

Code Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# file to parse, submit to memory
tree = ET.parse('JuniperXmlConf-Name-NewSSLVPNA.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Defining the relevant root by tag.  Children of a Root Tag

user_realms = root[3][0]
user_roles = root[3][1]


#Defining dictionaries Children of Children (subelements)

name = []
idletimeout = []
maxtimeout = []
reminder = []
limit_concurrent_users = []
guaranteed_minimum = []
maximum = []
max_sessions_per_user = []
user_names = []

# Parsing Data into Lists from User_Roles. 
#Notice .text method

for child in user_roles:
    try:
        name.append(child[0].text)
    except IndexError:
        continue
...
...

# Counter displays data as name is argument

i = 0
for value in (name):
    try:
        i += 1
        print("Name: {}, Idletimeout {}, Maxtimeout {}, Reminder {}".format(name[i], 
            idletimeout[i], maxtimeout[i], reminder[i]))
    except IndexError:
        break 

"""
Example of XML:
"""

<users>
        <user-realms>
            <realm>
                <name>Customer Name here</name>
                <authentication-policy>
                    <source-ip>
                        <customized>any-ip</customized>
                        <ips>
                        </ips>
                    </source-ip>
                    <browser>
                        <customized>user-agent here</customized>
                        <user-agent-patterns>
                        </user-agent-patterns>
                    </browser>
    ........
    ........
    <users>
            <user-realms>
                <realm>
                    <name></name>
                    <authentication-policy>
                        <source-ip>
                            <customized>any-ip</customized>
                            <ips>
                            </ips>
                        </source-ip>
                        <browser>
                            <customized>user-agent here</customized>
                            <user-agent-patterns>
                            </user-agent-patterns>
                        </browser>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `lxml` and `XPath` to search for your elements?

Comment: So I can find my Elements no problem.  I could use lxml or XPath to search the elements, but I think I'll get the same result.  During the for loop when the iteration comes across an empty element, I think it skips the element and appends nothing, moving on to appending the next element.  So what that does is when I am creating multiple lists that have a 1 to 1 relationship.  One list may have a index skipped, because during the iteration of an element.tag, the element.text was empty.  So when I display the output, the information is inaccurate, the list does not line up.

Comment: do you have a XML sample?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE,  As you can see from the example above, one section of the XML document element tag <name> has text and the second portion of the document doesn't. When I append the .text of an element.tag I am successful. So getting to the elements isn't a problem.  As the for loop continues, the second element <name>  within the XML document is empty.  I think the for loop does not append empty elements into the list.  So when I try to make a 1 to 1 relationship between lists, the data is inaccurate.  This is tough to explain.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if there is logic that will help append "None" into a list, when a <name> element tag's text is empty.